# What are the advantages of Hydra flame thrower vs the Neptune heavy machine?

Tags: templar-assault-rpg

I am playing Templar Assault RPG on my Android, and I use either the the Hydra or the Neptune, but the squad of 4 is too small to use both.

What are the pros and cons of each? and when should I choose one over the other?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Take a look at our [About page](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/about) to get an idea of what this site is all about. In particular, this question is purely about opinion, which is off topic. If you can rephrase it so that it can have a "right" answer instead of asking for opinions, we can help you better!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - wow, thanks for the help!  I will try to fix it.

Comment: It looks like someone has already given it a once-over to make it more about objective things, but if you can think of more details to add, don't hesitate. :)